# NSTableView view based 'Image & Text Table Cell View' not recognizing my custom NSImageView subclass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

1. First i changed my `NSTableView` to view based and created an
   `IBOutlet` of my `NSTableView`.
2. Then i dragged the `Image & Text Table Cell View` to it.
3. After that i changed the `NSImageView` that's inside that cell view
   to my custom `NSImageView` subclass: 'PVAsyncImageView'.
4. I imported it on my .h.

And i have this code:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    [[result imageView] downloadImageFromURL:@"lol"];
    return result;
}
```

But it's not recognizing `downloadImageFromURL` (a method from my `NSImageView` subclass). Xcode gives me an error.
Any thoughts?

Comment: no, it doesn't even run. xcode error

Comment: did you check with my answer...if it still not working, please post the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either your subclass isn't really overriding -init:, or you aren't properly loading your subclass..
2. Be sure there's no typo in the method name on the subclass: if you have, for instance, -init: in the subclass, the superclass's -init: will still be called.
3. Are you overriding -allocWithZone: or something somehow?

Comment: i figured it out! i have to create my NSTableCellView subclass and create an `IBOutlet` of my PVAsyncImageView and it's working now. thanks anyway!

Comment: but it's stupid. if i change the subclass of the nsimageview that comes with the 'Image & Text Table Cell View' it should do the job...